# JQuery REST Get XML Payload

Tags: jquery, xml, rest

I am calling an internal REST service that returns an XML payload as below. Nothing seems to be rendered on the front end though the server log is returning a 200 and XML payload. Below is the jQuery. The Firefox debug console indicates 200 also doesn't thinks CORS is involved here. I have tried changing dataType to XML and then trying to serialize doesn't work also. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
var rootURL = "http://mydomain:8999/";
function findByName(searchKey) {
    console.log('findByName: ' + searchKey);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: rootURL + searchKey,
        //contentType: "text/xml",
        dataType: "text",
        processData: false,
        //contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
        success: renderList,
        failure: function(errMsg) {
            console.log('errMsg: ' + errMsg);
            alert(errMsg);
        }
    });
}



function renderList(data) {
    console.log("Hello There: ");
    $('#data').append(data);

}
```

From Firefox debug console:

```
 GET http://mydomain:8999/4 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 571ms]
09:15:07.393 "findByName: 4"
```

XML Payload returned by server

```
<CUSTOMER xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<ID>3</ID>
<FIRSTNAME>Michael</FIRSTNAME>
<LASTNAME>Clancy</LASTNAME>
<STREET>542 Upland Pl.</STREET>
<CITY>San Francisco</CITY>
</CUSTOMER>
```

Comment: Aren't you using `renderList` instead of calling `renderList(data)`? According to jQuery docs: `success: function(PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR)`.